# Probability of drawing an ace from a reduced set of cards

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say you have a deck of $52$ cards, $4$ of which are aces.  The odds of drawing an ace from this deck are $4/52 \approx 8\%$.

But you're not drawing from the full deck.  Instead, you have a deck of only $10$ cards, randomly pulled from the full $52$-card deck.  What's the chance of drawing an ace from this reduced deck?

All $4$ aces might have made it into this deck, in which case the odds would be $4/10 = 40\%$.  But maybe none of the aces made it, leaving the odds of drawing one at $0\%$.

**What is the distribution of the odds of drawing an ace from the reduced deck?**

Comment: Shouldn't they be the same, i.e. 1/13? These two are like flipping the top of 52 cards, and flipping the top of top 10 cards of 52 cards, if the 52 cards are shuffled randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the distribution of the odds of drawing an ace from the reduced deck, the odds is 0 if the reduced deck contains no ace, i.e.

$$\Pr \left( odds = 0 \right) = \frac{\binom{48}{10}}{\binom{52}{10}}$$

for the $\binom{48}{10}$ combinations out of the $\binom{52}{10}$ combinations which gives no aces in the reduced set.

Similarly,

$$\Pr \left( odds = 10\% \right) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{10}}$$

Hope you now know the rest, and check the probability of getting an ace at last is still $\frac{1}{13}$.

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, there's a 10% chance that the reduced set will contain 1 ace?  (If so, then I'm following you and can calculate the rest.)

Comment: No, the chance that the reduced set will contain 1 ace is $\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{10}}$, around 42%. This case corresponds to "the odds of drawing an ace from the reduced set" equals 10%.

Comment: There's a 42% chance of getting the reduced set where you have a 10% chance of getting an ace.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes right yes right (this is not a spam)

Comment: @peterwhy People here often add `${}{}{}{}{}$` to comments to bulk them up over the minimum length. It renders like this: ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_S$ be the probability of randomly picking an ace from a set $S$ of $10$ cards.  We note that $p_S$ varies only with the number of aces in $S$.  More specifically, $$p_S=\frac{\text{nr aces in } S}{10}.$$

The number of aces in $S$ must be in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, since there are only $4$ aces in a deck of cards.  Hence $p_S \in \{0,1/10,2/10,3/10,4/10\}$.

If we choose $S$ uniformly at random from the set of all $10$-subsets of a deck of $52$ playing cards, then, for $i \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(p_S=i/10) &= \mathrm{Pr}(\text{nr aces in } S \text{ is } i) \\
&=\frac{\text{nr 10-subsets with } i \text{ aces}}{\text{total nr 10-subsets}} \\
&= \frac{\binom{4}{i}\binom{48}{10-i}}{\binom{52}{10}}
\end{align*}
since $S$ comprises of $i$ aces and $10-i$ non-aces.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of drawing an ace out of ten randomly selected cards is 1/13, as peterwhy explains in his comment:  The card drawn is equally likely to be each of the fifty-two cards.

Please be careful in your use of the terms "probability" and "odds."

Comment: Careful in what way?

Comment: Probability and odds are different things.  You may look them up.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking that may convince you the correct value is $\left(\frac{1}{13}\right)$:

Before you start with the standard deck, take the $1-10$ of some suit, mix them up and pick one at random.  Say it's the $7$. Remember that!

Put the complete deck back together and shuffle it well.  You're going to take the top ten as your random subset of $10$, and then take the $7-th$ card as your pick from the subset (That's why you did the first pick, remember?).  The top ten cards are random, 'cause you shuffled well.  The choice of a particular one from the 10 is random.  All the specs have been met.

So, what's the probability that the $7-th$ card down in the shuffled deck is an ace?